# Not able to merge dictionaries into a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, extend

So I have this piece of code to generate some response for api response.

```
    @app.route("/api/topFour",methods = ['POST'])
def top():
    parser = request.get_json()
    user_id = parser["user_id"]
    item = {}
    answer = []
    parameters = {"user_id":user_id,"start_date":"2018-01-01","last_date":"2019-12-31"}
    response = requests.post("https://my_doamin/app/api/get-customer-list",params= parameters)
    data = response.json()
    if data["status"] == "1":
        customer_list = data["customerList"]
        print(customer_list)
        for i in customer_list:
            item["customer_id"]= i["id"]
            item["customer_name"]=i["company_name"]
            print(item)
            answer.extend(item)
    return jsonify({"user_id":user_id,"top4user": answer})
```

so In my cmd : this is the output for customer-list:

```
[{'id': 422689, 'full_name': 'jeff bezos', 'company_name': 'Amazon inc', 'create_date': '2019-03-08 17:38:48'}, {'id': 423053, 'full_name': 'akshit', 'company_name': 'HP Globalsoft pvt ltd', 'create_date': '2019-03-09 12:31:42'}, {'id': 422666, 'full_name': 'bill gates', 'company_name': 'Microsoft C
orporation', 'create_date': '2019-03-08 17:16:26'}, {'id': 423034, 'full_name': 'mukesh', 'company_name': 'Reliance Industries Limited', 'create_date': '2019-03-09 12:26:15'}]
```

and this for print(item):

```
{'customer_id': 422689, 'customer_name': 'Amazon inc'}
{'customer_id': 423053, 'customer_name': 'HP Globalsoft pvt ltd'}
{'customer_id': 422666, 'customer_name': 'Microsoft Corporation'}
{'customer_id': 423034, 'customer_name': 'Reliance Industries Limited'}
```

But When I extend this into a list, it's giving this response:

```
{
    "top4user": [
        "customer_id",
        "customer_name",
        "customer_id",
        "customer_name",
        "customer_id",
        "customer_name",
        "customer_id",
        "customer_name"
    ],
    "user_id": 6052
}
```

The following is the output that I was expecting:

```
[
{'customer_id': 423034, 'customer_name': 'Reliance Industries Limited'}, 
{'customer_id': 423034, 'customer_name': 'Reliance Industries Limited'}, 
{'customer_id': 423034, 'customer_name': 'Reliance Industries Limited'},
{'customer_id': 423034, 'customer_name': 'Reliance Industries Limited'}
]
```

It should be a list of dictionaries. I tried with append.

**edit:** This was a time when I was a beginner and was frustrated. Please provide feedback in comment rather than just adding negetivity. Helping to improve is better I guess.

Comment: I am not clear what you want to achieve, can you provide your expected output?

Comment: [{'customer_id': 423034, 'customer_name': 'Reliance Industries Limited'}, {'customer_id': 423034, 'customer_name': 'Reliance Industries Limited'}, {'customer_id': 423034, 'customer_name': 'Reliance Industries Limited'}, {'customer_id': 423034, 'customer_name': 'Reliance Industries Limited'}]

It should be like this only but in this names are same.. its basically a list of dictionary should come.

Comment: Create a new `item` dict for every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
for i in customer_list:
    item = {}
    item["customer_id"] = i["id"]
    item["customer_name"] = i["company_name"]
    print(item)
    answer.append(item)
```

The following is the output:

```
[
  {'customer_id': 422689, 'customer_name': 'Amazon inc'}, 
  {'customer_id': 423053, 'customer_name': 'HP Globalsoft pvt ltd'}, 
  {'customer_id': 422666, 'customer_name': 'Microsoft Corporation'}, 
  {'customer_id': 423034, 'customer_name': 'Reliance Industries Limited'}
]
```

Comment: yeah see all the elements are same?

Comment: just a second please

Comment: It's only giving key values with extend!

Comment: yeah, but in the solution i have used `append` instead of extend, and created a new dict inside the `for` loop